# How to Search on Google the users input and Open it in a browser without errors?

Tags: python, python-requests

Want to make a python code, so that if the user inputs his search words in IDE it should take the user to google website.

Comment: Well,What have you tried?

Comment: Sentamil,  please provide your tried code or anything which is close to the question. We can help you rectify mistakes or give you an apt answer but cannot provide you answer without you trying for it.

Comment: Please reconsider the answer you chose as the answer. He copied mine

Comment: Also his answer shows error to what patrick specified. i've added a solution to it

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. I am new here and learning many things.I will correct all m,y mistakes in my post next time.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import webbrowser # the module to open url

sear=input("Enter your search: ").strip().replace(' ','+') # converting search input to a perfect query

URL='https://google.com/search?q=' + sear #creating the url

webbrowser.open_new_tab(URL) # opening the url
```

Also sentences including some special charecters like 'Hams&Eggs' intent to cause problem. Here we use `quote()` from `urllib`:

```
import webbrowser # the module to open url
from urllib.parse import quote # to encode to percentage encoding
sear=input("Enter your search: ").strip() # converting search input to a perfect query

URL='https://google.com/search?q=' + quote(sear) #creating the url

webbrowser.open_new_tab(URL) # opening the url
```

Now, to open the first result in the google search:

```
import requests , webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sear=input("Enter your search: ").strip().replace(' ','+')

URL='https://google.com/search?q=' + sear

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
resp = requests.get(URL,headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
webbrowser.open_new_tab(soup.find_all('div',class_='r')[0].find('a')['href'])
```

Now to open all result links:

```
import requests , webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sear=input("Enter your search: ").strip().replace(' ','+')

URL='https://google.com/search?q=' + sear

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
resp = requests.get(URL,headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
for i in soup.find_all('div',class_='r'):
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(i.find('a')['href'])
```

Comment: Maybe they think you used an unnecessary string-processing method.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA is it now perfect?

Comment: I don't know what he expect,I don't downvote your post.

Comment: You should always URL-quote() when you try to put text into an url - there are many more characters that lead to bad results then & (which is used to seperate url - parameters). "§$%/() f.e. need to be encoded as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
import webbrowser

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='   #Search Query Url 

search_words = input("Search your words")   # User inputs data as per search requirements

webbrowser.open(url+search_words)          # Opens the webbrowser
```

Comment: please dont copy answers in SO

Comment: Though the answer is same, the representation of code matters with comments and the person who asked question is new to the community, so it is my duty to provide an unambiguous answer with easy explanations so that he doesn't get more confused

Comment: Input "Bread & egg" - see also [Stance on answering bad questions & it's dupes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions). Copying another answer verbatim to add comments on things that are very obvious in what they do leaves a bad taste. You could have edited the other answer and added the comments there - to be accepted if it is a "worthwile" addition.